# Catch upstream down (502) errors and display custom error page

Tags: nginx, custom-errors

This question should have been answered a longtime ago, but I can't seem to figure it out despite reading many common answers, can someone please point out why my configuration isn't working?

**Goal: when upstream server_api is down (say, its worker processes has crashed), I want nginx to display my custom error page.**

My configuration:

```
location @server {
    proxy_pass http://server_api;
    proxy_redirect off;
    ...

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 502 /error-502.html;
}

error_page 502 /error-502.html;

location = /error-502.html {
    internal;
    root /srv/my-server/html;
}
```

My steps:

- I have my static error page at `/srv/my-server/html/error-502.html` ready, same permission and owners as other static assets.
- I have stopped my upstream service, and see `[error] 2359#0: *25 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` appearing in logs.
- Now I try to make my custom error page show up for 502 errors.
- I have tried setting `error_page` at both or either `server` or `location` block.
- I have tried `error_page` with `proxy_intercept_errors on` in the `location` or `server` block;

None of them appear to persuade nginx to display my error page. Why not? What have I missed?

Comment: Post the complete `server` block.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thx, I figured it out finally, please see if there are any flaws in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Justin and Michael for pointing me in the right direction, it indeed is a location block causing my troubles, in particular:

```
location / {
    try_files   $uri $uri/ @server;
    error_page  403 = @server;
}
```

Basically, I was trying to be clever and catch `$uri/` error (403 happens when you try to access a folder that exists but has no index file or auto-indexing) and redirect it to `@server` block as well.

But isn't `try_files $uri $uri/ @server;` alone enough?

Imagine you trying to access `http://example.com/`, nginx will say, oh this folder exists (it's your `root`) but no index found, and throw 403 instead of passing onto `@server` block.

Thus my 403 solution, but I didn't realize it comes with a cost: this means nginx already caught an error and used `error_page` in the same `location` block to handle it (by passing it to `@server`).

Couple this with my tests in the question, it suggests nginx (v1.7.x) will ignore further `error_page` directive at this point and use default 502 instead.

**The interesting part: how do we workaround this?**

My solution is to setup an exact matching root route instead, now catching 403 on root isn't necessary anymore, and `error_page` works as intended.

```
error_page 502 /error-502.html;

location = /error-502.html {
    internal;
    root /srv/example.com/html;
}

location = / {
    try_files $uri @server;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @server;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to say for sure without seeing your entire configuration, because this works for me without any of the extra measures you've taken.  I first tried all of your config, then stripped away bits one by one to see if anything changed.

It shouldn't be necessary to use proxy_intercept_errors, because the 502 is generated by nginx itself when it fails to connect to the backend.  I confirmed that this worked for me with this set and unset.

All I've added, inside of my server block is:

```
error_page 502 /error-502.html;

location = /error-502.html {
  internal;
  root /srv/www/errors;
}
```

In my setup, my static error pages are in /srv/www/errors, but nothing else is different.

You must have configuration elsewhere that is server-wide or in your server block which interferes or overrides.  Pay attention to the precedence rules for locations, that could be a factor.

Comment: Thx, I figured it out finally, please see if there are any flaws in my answer.